# Filtering Gridview w/ SQL & cmd.Parameters

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a Gridview ( GridView1) that needs to be filtered using 4 DropDownLists
Right now I'm only trying to filter by the first two selections.

DdlVendor
DdlStore

I'm accomplishing it by using a SQL Query

```
        string query = "Select DISTINCT *, dbo.getsource(version, store_account) as source " + 
                        " FROM TABLENAME " +
                        " WHERE (name=@name or @name = '') " +
                        " and (store_name=@Sname or @Sname = '') " + 
                        " and canceled = 0 " +
                        " and (trans_date between @start and @end) and User_id not in (45493,43020,45491) and internal_use = 0  " + 
                        " order by " + sort + " ";
```

The filter currently takes out all test orders sent by us, if you're wondering what all the extra shenanigans is.

```
 using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
           using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", DdlVendor.SelectedIndex > 0 ? DdlVendor.SelectedValue : "");
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sname", DdlStore.SelectedIndex > 0 ? DdlStore.SelectedValue : "");
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", start);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end", end);
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
```

@Name and @Sname are what I'm using for the first two dropdownlists. The problem is when I get done selecting my values and apply them the GridView goes blank with no error.

The goal is to filter what you see in the gridview by the values selected in each dropdownlist.

I'll clarify any questions you have to the best of my abilities.

Here's one of my DropDownLists

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DdlVendor" AppendDataBoundItems="True" runat="server" CssClass="form-control ftxt" PropertyName="SelectedValue" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Dist_num" AutoPostBack="True">
            <asp:ListItem Text="ALL" Value=""/>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DATABASE %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Name], [Dist_num] FROM [VIEWNAME]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Here's my GridView with a Boundfield as an example

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" Width="100%"  CssClass="main-table"  AutoGenerateColumns="False">

<asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Vendor" ItemStyle-Width="80px" SortExpression="Name" />
```

Comment: When a GridView rebinds empty it usually means the select failed. Have you tested the select statement with forced inputs? i.e. running it in SSMS with the variables declared and set?

Comment: I haven't thought of that. I usually don't have permission to access the Tables and Views. I only use what's given to me. I can give it shot.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

The entire time I was trying to store an alphabetical value as a numerical value.

So by changing

```
"WHERE (name=@name or @name = '') " +
```

To

```
" WHERE (Dist_num=@name or @name = '') " +
```

The Gridview filters beautifully. Same with the second query

```
" and (store_name=@Sname or @Sname = '') " +
```

to

```
" and (store_Account=@Sname or @Sname = '') " +
```